# Objective-c Initialise Property

Tags: objective-c, cordova, initialization

Im my 2.0.1 phonegap application I added a property to the MainViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* test;
```

I then initialise the property in the initWithNibName method like phonegap suggests.

```
test = @"test";
```

This works fine, however I have seen some people do the following to initialise there properties instead:

```
test = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

I thought that the @property would have already been allocated to memory and initialised as a string already so no need to do all of that o.0 :S?

Whats the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

To properly initialize a property you should be using `self.test = @"test"`. The use of `[[NSString alloc] init];` is absolutely pointless and there is no reason anyone should do that. If you want an empty string instead of `nil`, which is the default value for member variables (and synthesized properties) of class types, you can simply set test to `@""`, `self.test = @""`.

> I thought that the @property would have already been allocated to
>   memory and initialised as a string already so no need to do all of
>   that o.0 :S?

As I mentioned above, member variables, including those synthesized by properties, will be set to their default values which will be `nil` in this case.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought I was doing it right as it seemed to work fine, however I have seen alot of people say you shouldt use self. in the init and dealloc methods as the class will no be complete created?

Comment: That is another back and forth argument. Once `self = [super init]` is complete in the initializer you are good to go. I would avoid using `self.` in dealloc however.

Comment: ahh okay, I just looked and saw if (self) in the initWithNibName method that has created by phonegap, where I have been doing the intiatlisation. I guess that must mean the class is setup like u say :p Thanks, is it at this point okay to do either then?

Comment: Yes, I added to avoid using `self.` in `dealloc`. Either method works in the initializer but using `self.` will properly store the object in an initializer. For example if your initializer took a parameter that set `test` and you assigned it directly to `test` instead of `self.test` then it would not copy it. If a `NSMutableString` was passed and the caller later changes it, it could leave your object in an undesirable state.